# Navigation bar and logo on same line?

Tags: html, css

How do I get the navigation bar to appear next to the logo instead of breaking to the next line under it?
I've tried several changes but it keeps going onto the next line.  I'm trying to avoid using floats because I was told they are not good to use.  I want it to look like the navigation bar on this website in this end:
http://www.freecsstemplates.org/

I would like to understand how it is being done on that website.

I am just very confused as to how the process is to work.

CSS:

```
#header
{
background-image:url('menubg.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
#logo
{
display:inline-block;
}
#menu ul
{
display:inline-block;
list-style-type:none;
padding: 0px;
margin:0px;
}

#menu li
{
display:inline-block;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#menu a:link,a:visited
{
display:inline-block;
text-transform:lowercase;
width:auto;
font-weight:bold;
padding-left:47.5px;
padding-right:47.5px;
padding-top:9px;
padding-bottom:9px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#57fafc;
text-align:center;
background-color:#62d2d3;
}

#menu a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#7ce5e6;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css">
<title>Blah</title></head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<div id="logo"><img src="logo.png" /></div>
<div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a 

href="#">Contact</a></li><li><a href="#">About</a></li><li><a 

href="#">Products</a></li><li><a href="#">Design-a-Tee</a></li><li><a 

href="#">Reviews/Testimonials</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put the logo inside the `ul` element.

Comment: I want to control the distance of the logo from the rest of the navigation bar, if I add it then it will just be lined up with the rest of the links, won't it?

Comment: you could use the nth child selector for styling the first li. see here for an exlanation  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child

Comment: whoever told you floats are bad is wrong so ignore that bad advice.  An item that takes up a full line is display : block.  If you change that to display : inline or inline-block then the elements will be on the same line.

Comment: To expand on Honorable Chow's point: there are very few absolutes in web development. Sometimes floats are the wrong tool, sometimes they are the right tool, and only study and experience will help you figure out which is which.

Comment: How do I align the navigation bar vertically?

Answer (score 1):

add this css

```
#logo {
    float:left;
}
#menu {
    float:right;    
}
#header {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}
```